# In normal mode why does `q:` bring up a command history?

Tags: vim, neovim

If I am in vim normal mode and I type `q:` a quick-fix window pops up with a history of recent commands.

I'm stumped at how this works, `q` is for recording macros, is it unexpected behaviour because the `:` is not a register?

I looked in `:help q` but couldn't see anything that made sense there.

Comment: This is standard functionality.  Look at `:help q:`. `q:` by default brings up the command line history.

Comment: If I do that I seem to get a pop up quick help window for ack.vim ...

Comment: Yes, I do not have the ack.vim syntax file nor its help file.  I do see that its help file does have an entry for `q:`.  You can lookup `:help cmdline-window` and `:help cmdline-history`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow `:help ":`, you'll see that register `:` is a *read-only* register. Recording a macro into it is not possible. Therefore, there's no clash with macro recording.

The `q:` command enters the *command-line-window*; yes, this is similar in appearance (and also somewhat in behavior) to *quickfix windows*. You'll find it documented at `:help q:`, or `:help cmdline-window`.

Comment: Relevant [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/)

Comment: Yes, the command-line window is great (because the full power of Vim editing commands is available there). Too bad so many people only discovery it by accident...

Answer (score 2):

**q: in normal mode results in displaying the command line history**

A history is maintained of ex commands, searches, expressions input lines and debugging mode commands.

The normal command, `q:`, puts you in the ex command history where you edit your command history.  It has similarities to the ex command, `:history`.

The following help articles discuss this:

`:help cmdline-history`
`:help cmdline-window`

There is a lot of value in being able to review these histories.

Ingo addresses your questions pertaining to registers and clashing.

Answer (score 0):

[vimhelp#q:](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#q:)

> 2. From Normal mode, use the "q:", "q/" or "q?" command.
>      This starts editing an Ex command-line ("q:") or search string ("q/" or
>      "q?")...
>
> When the window opens it is filled with the command-line history.